# Не запускается NET Core Web App

Tags: linux, .net, ubuntu, asp.net, asp.net-core

Всем привет.
В общем, создаю я web app прямо на сервере (dotnet new webapp), собираю и запускаю. В консоли отображается, что приложение доступно по ссылке localhost:port. В хроме я перехожу по ip:port, но к сайту доступ получить не получается. Пытался и порты поменять, никак не решается... Помогите пожалуйста, уже 4 дня такая проблема...

Comment: Если оно висит на localhost, то снаружи вы его и не увидите. Вешайте его на ip внешнего интерфейса сервера или на все доступные

Comment: Так если после dotnet run приложение доступно по ссылке localhost:5000, если я вместо localhost вставлю публичный IP, сайт не будет доступным? А почему в оф. документации об этом ничего не говорится?

Comment: там наоборот даже написано, чтобы проверить работу приложения, напишите dotnet run и перейдите по http://serverip:port.

Comment: Говорится в оф.доке. Просто там много чего написано. В общем по умолчанию кестрел смотрит на localhost. И нужно [переопределить в коде, через конфиг или параметры вызова](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#override-configuration). Там localhost, потому что нечего кестрел наружу выставлять. По задумке в проде перед ним должен стоять полноценный сервер типа nginx

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, помогло !!!!! Очень благодарен

Comment: Только теперь одна проблема. Не открывается phpmyadmin через ip/phpmyadmin. Файл существует в /var/www/html. До этого нормально открывалось, теперь пишет, что страница не найдена

Comment: А phpmyadmin тут причем. Это вообще php и к asp.net не имеет никакого отношения.